Exclude CRS rules for some specific URLs
I am a newcomer to OWASP ModSecurity, and I wanted to know how I should exclude some specific rules for certain URLs.
I've searched and found that I should exclude them in the modsecurity.conf file, but I don't exactly know where it is. Once I find it, I'm not sure how to write the command. I couldn't find anything in the documentation pages.
For example for this rule:
SecRule REQUEST_URI ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "@rx ((?:[~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|:;\"'´’‘`<>][^~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|:;\"'´’‘`<>]*?){2})" \
    "id:942432,\
    phase:2,\
    block,\
    capture,\
    t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,\
    msg:'Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection (args): # of special characters exceeded (2)',\
    logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.1} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',\
    tag:'application-multi',\
    tag:'language-multi',\
    tag:'platform-multi',\
    tag:'attack-sqli',\
    tag:'paranoia-level/4',\
    tag:'OWASP_CRS',\
    tag:'capec/1000/152/248/66',\
    tag:'PCI/6.5.2',\
    ver:'OWASP_CRS/4.8.0',\
    severity:'WARNING',\
    setvar:'tx.inbound_anomaly_score_pl4=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score}',\
    setvar:'tx.sql_injection_score=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score}'"



The mentioned rule from CRS 4.8.0 is 942432. The file modsecurity.org is part of ModSecurity. If you want to make an exclusion, you should put it into REQUEST-900-EXCLUSIONS-BEFORE.conf.
First, copy/move this file without .example suffix, then add the exclusions which would be something like this:
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /your/uri" \
    "id:10000,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveById=942432"

This rule will prevent to execution of the rule 942432 IF the uri begins with /your/uri.
For more information, please read the tuning section of CRS.
